# Port forwarding on a FortiGate firewall sitting behind an ISP router

Tags: port, port-forwarding, fortigate

I have a FortiGate firewall (30E) which is sitting behind a router (provided by ISP).
The router has allocated local IP to the firewall and from this firewall subnet is created on which the server is running.
[image]

```
Router -> Global IP
Firewall -> 172.135.0.2 (Gateway address)
Server -> 10.0.0.3
```

**Goal:** I would like to expose an application (hosted on server's localhost) to the external internet.

To achieve this, I have tried creating `virtual IP` and `IPv4 policy` to forward the local port.

For example:

```
application is running on `10.0.0.3:8080/app`
port forwd (virutal ip): `172.135.0.2 --> 10.0.0.3 (8080 --> 8080)`
```

Following this, I exposed the port `8080` on the router:

```
port forwd (router) : 172.135.0.2:8080
```

So i used the gateway address of firewall as the application IP address and open it as HTTP service on my router.
**However, i still cannot access application from outside.**

May I ask, how to expose this application.
Please, suggest advice or ideas to make this work. Thanks look forward to all the responses.
I have So my router is allocating local IP address to the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was caused by policy 99 located within 'local in policy' on the Fortigate, separate from 'Firewall Policy'

After the change the Fortigate now processes port forwarding from the ISP router

Previously it was dropping the traffic

#Open CLI

- Check firewall local-in-policy
- Check whether policy 99 is set to allow

  ```
    HOSTNAME (Customer VDOM) # config firewall local-in-policy
    HOSTNAME (local-in-policy) # edit 99
    HOSTNAME (99) # show full-configuration
    config firewall local-in-policy
        edit 99
            set uuid 278aa3a8-46c3-51ec-87a4-43a5674cc8ef
            set intf "UNTRUST"
            set srcaddr "all"
            set dstaddr "all"
            set action deny
            set service "ALL"
            set schedule "always"
            set status enable
            set comments ''
        next
    end
  ```

If so change 'action' to allow

```
HOSTNAME (99) # set action accept
HOSTNAME (99) # end
```